# Проблема с доступом к json- server через expo на телефоне

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, react-native, expo

Я недавно начал заниматься react native. У меня такая проблема возникла.

Запускаю приложение и оно работает захожу в подпункт где данные берутся с сервера json а там пусто. Пишет network request failed. Как я понял данные с сервера не считываются.

Тут поподробнее.

Сначала запускаю json server набираю
json-server --watch db.json -p 3001 в командной строке. Все запустилось. Захлжу в браузер набираю localhos:3001/books. И данные появляются. Как я понял отвечает на запрос.

Далее запускаю react native. Все загружается, запускается в браузере metro bundler (localhost:19002). Все норм есть три вида запуска программы на телефоне:

1.local и адрес 127.0.0.1, как я понял нужен для подключения и запуска через usb кабель. Пробовал этим методом приложение запускается. А данные не появляются. Пишет network request failed.

2.lan и ip адрес компа, как я понял через вай фай чтоль. Так как уменя нет wifi роутера, попробовалс моего же компа раздать вайфай. Подключил модем. И начал раздачу вайфая. Подключил телефон и запустил. Вообще не запустилось. Ip адрес компа в режиме lan по умолчанию ip адрес от модема(192.168.8.100) а телефона (192.168.43.216). Короче телефон и комп должны быть в одной локальной сети. Дай думаю возьму еще один комп. Он будет раздавать вай фай типа вместо роутера. А свой рабочий комп и телефон потом подключу к нему.  Вроде бы раздача вайфай есть  подключился настроил ip адреса. Все еще не запускается. Похоже не корректно сформировал сеть. Я не специалист в локальных сетях. Если есть идеи помогите.

3.tunnel не совсем понял что это решил раздать вай фай с телефона точку доступа сделать. Подключил комп  запустил. Вроде запустилось но все равно не показывает данные.

Пожалуйста помогите. 
1) Организать lan соединение.
2) как считывать данные с json servera на телефон.

P.s. 3 дня угробил пытаясь  разобраться.

Comment: `network request failed` - Нужно более подробное сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Просто не улается получить данные с json- server

Comment: Просто понятно. Теперь сложно давайте.